# How do I use %in% inside of filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two data sets: `sales_by_week` and `top_sellers`.  I'm trying to make a graph of the data in `sales_by_week` for my top 10 ranked items out of `top_sellers`.  I'm struggling on the `filter` part using `%in%`.  I want to filter the data to only 10 product IDs.

```
sales_by_week %>%
  filter(product_id %in% c(filter(top_sellers, rank <= 10) %>%   # HOW DO I DO THIS LINE?
  select(product_id))) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  summarize(sales_qty = sum(sales_qty)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = week)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = sales_qty, color = product_id))
```

With the code above, I get the error `Error in filter_impl(.data, dots) : comparison (4) is possible only for atomic and list types`

My data looks like this

[image]

[image]

How do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample dataframe this is kind of tough to do completely, but i think this should roughly work.

```
top = top_sellers[top_sellers$rank <= 10, ]
sales_by_week = sales_by_week[sales_by_week$product_id %in% top$product_id, ]
```

It looks like sales_by_week only has numbers and top_products has letters, so the gsub will remove all the numbers. if that's wrong just delete that part.

Your line would look like

```
filter(product_id %in% top$product_id)
```

Comment: When I try that, I get `Error in strsplit(gsub("[^0-9]", "", top$product_id)) : 
  argument "split" is missing, with no default`

Comment: `sales_by_week$product_id` is actually character data.  The sample data I showed only has the value "1457", but most of the rows have both letters and numbers.